# Double bracketed method syntax.

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, syntax

I have a question about a certain type of method syntax.

For example I know what this does ..

```
NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc]init...blablabla];
```

The alloc is performed on the class (NSString in this case) and the init is performed on the instance of the class..

If we have

```
[variable method];
```

I know how that functions too.. the method is performed on "variable"

if I have

```
variable = [instance method];
```

the "method" method is performed on instance and stored in variable..

But where I get lost is at something that looks like this ..

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]something:parameter];
```

I'm not sure what action is being performed where..

Comment: It's important to understand that what you're talking about is not procedural.  The method is not being performed on the variable or class.  You're sending a message to to the variable or class, and in this specific case, the message you're sending happens to be the name of a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[CCDirector sharedDirector]` is getting the singleton instance of the director.  Then you are calling the `something` method with `parameter`.  It would be similar to doing this

```
CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director something:parameter];
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets mean the same everywhere. The message expression `[object arg0:value arg1:value ...]` sends the message `@selector(arg0:arg1:...)` to `object` (which could itself be a message expression). The message handler can return an object, so the value of a message expression can itself be the recipient of another message. Nesting these expressions is the same as nesting function calls:

```
something(CCDirector_sharedDirector(), parameter);
```

`CCDirector_sharedDirector()` doesn't actually exist; it's just used for comparison.

Note that in:

```
[[NSString alloc] init...]
```

It's not so much that `init` is sent to an NSString instance (it isn't, as `[NSString  alloc]` actually returns an [NSCFString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393873/)), it's that `init` is sent to the result of `[NSString alloc]`.

If you find nested messages hard to read, you can break them into multiple lines or use [temporary variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401704/).

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]
    something:parameter];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[CCDirector sharedDirector]` is a method on `CCDirector`, and returns some object.  Much like `[NSString alloc]`.  The rest of the line calls a method on the object that's returned.

Answer (score 0):

As @hspain pointed out, its a convention used to denote a singleton instance.  The actual alloc/init occurs, and is only occured once, within sharedDirector.

[Here is more information](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/) on the singleton pattern in objective-c.